# Using Trim on property "breaks" SQL that it returns no results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

Let's consider this kinda pseudo code (C#):

Take a look at those `.Trim()`

```
var trim = universalSearch.Trim().ToLower(); // value is "oo"

(x.Prop1.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop2.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop3.Name.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop4.Name2.Trim().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop5.Name3.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop6.Prop6A.Name.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop6.Prop6B.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
(x.Prop7 != null && x.Prop7.Name.Trim().ToLower().Contains(trim)))
```

Generated SQL by this Predicate looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Orders" AS x

MANY JOINS

WHERE (x."IsRemoved" = FALSE) 
AND 
(
    (
        ("x.Prop3"."Name" <> 'ended') 
        OR 
        "x.Prop3"."Name" IS NULL
    ) 
    AND 
    (
        (
            (   

                (
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(x."Prop1", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0) 
                            OR (STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(x."Prop2", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0)) 
                        OR (STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE("x.Prop3"."Name", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0))
                    OR (STRPOS(REGEXP_REPLACE("x.Prop4"."Name2", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1'), 'oo') > 0))
                OR (STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE("x.Prop5"."Name3", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0)) 
            OR (STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE("x.Prop6.Prop6A"."Name", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0))
        OR(STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE("x.Prop6"."Prop6B", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0)
    )
    OR
    (
        x."Prop7Id" IS NOT NULL AND (STRPOS(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE("x.Prop7"."Name", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')), 'oo') > 0))
    )
)
```

but it returns 0 records

after a while I decided that those `.Trim()` are kinda weird and changed that code to:

```
(x.Prop1.ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop2.ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop3.Name.ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop4.Name2.Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop5.Name3.ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop6.Prop6A.Name.ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
x.Prop6.Prop6B.ToLower().Contains(trim) ||
(x.Prop7 != null && x.Prop7.Name.ToLower().Contains(trim)))
```

and generated sql is totally different:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Orders" AS x

MANY JOINS

WHERE (x."IsRemoved" = FALSE) 
AND
(
    (
        ("x.Prop3"."Name" <> 'ended')
        OR 
        "x.Prop3"."Name" IS NULL
    )
    AND 
    (
        (
            (
                (                       
                    (
                        (
                            (
                                (STRPOS(LOWER(x."Prop1"), 'oo') > 0) 
                            OR (STRPOS(LOWER(x."Prop2"), 'oo') > 0))
                        OR (STRPOS(LOWER("x.Prop3"."Name"), 'oo') > 0))
                    OR (STRPOS("x.Prop4"."Name2", 'oo') > 0))
                OR (STRPOS(LOWER("x.Prop5"."Name3"), 'oo') > 0))
            OR (STRPOS(LOWER("x.Prop6.Prop6A"."Name"), 'oo') > 0)) 
        OR (STRPOS(LOWER("x.Prop6"."Prop6B"), 'oo') > 0)) OR (x."Prop7Id" IS NOT NULL AND (STRPOS(LOWER("x.Prop7"."Name"), 'oo') > 0))
    )
)
```

**but now it works fine.**

What's wrong with those `.Trim()` in first example? is it a bug?

`Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` Version: `2.1.1`

**MCVE:**

`dotnet new mvc` .NET Core 2.1

```
public class Test
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
    .AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<Context>(o => o.UseNpgsql(""))
    .BuildServiceProvider();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

---

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, Context ctx)
{
    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => ctx.Tests.Add(new Test { Name = x.ToString() }));

    ctx.SaveChanges();

    Console.Clear();

    var query = ctx.Tests.Where(x => x.Name.Trim().ToLower() == "5".Trim().ToLower());
    Console.WriteLine(query.ToSql());
    var read = query.ToList();

    Console.WriteLine();

    query = ctx.Tests.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "5".Trim().ToLower());
    Console.WriteLine(query.ToSql());
    var read2 = query.ToList();

    (...)
}
```

For debugging purposes - `.ToSql()` method:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    private static readonly TypeInfo QueryCompilerTypeInfo = typeof(QueryCompiler).GetTypeInfo();

    private static readonly FieldInfo QueryCompilerField = typeof(EntityQueryProvider).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields.First(x => x.Name == "_queryCompiler");

    private static readonly FieldInfo QueryModelGeneratorField = QueryCompilerTypeInfo.DeclaredFields.First(x => x.Name == "_queryModelGenerator");

    private static readonly FieldInfo DataBaseField = QueryCompilerTypeInfo.DeclaredFields.Single(x => x.Name == "_database");

    private static readonly PropertyInfo DatabaseDependenciesField = typeof(Database).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Single(x => x.Name == "Dependencies");

    public static string ToSql<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query) where TEntity : class
    {
        var queryCompiler = (QueryCompiler)QueryCompilerField.GetValue(query.Provider);
        var modelGenerator = (QueryModelGenerator)QueryModelGeneratorField.GetValue(queryCompiler);
        var queryModel = modelGenerator.ParseQuery(query.Expression);
        var database = (IDatabase)DataBaseField.GetValue(queryCompiler);
        var databaseDependencies = (DatabaseDependencies)DatabaseDependenciesField.GetValue(database);
        var queryCompilationContext = databaseDependencies.QueryCompilationContextFactory.Create(false);
        var modelVisitor = (RelationalQueryModelVisitor)queryCompilationContext.CreateQueryModelVisitor();
        modelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor<TEntity>(queryModel);
        var sql = modelVisitor.Queries.First().ToString();

        return sql;
    }
}
```

Generated SQLs:

With `x => x.Name.Trim().ToLower() == "5".Trim().ToLower()`:

```
SELECT x."Id", x."Name"
FROM "Tests" AS x
WHERE LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(x."Name", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')) = '5'
```

Result: 0 Rows

With `x => x.Name.ToLower() == "5".Trim().ToLower()`:

```
SELECT x."Id", x."Name"
FROM "Tests" AS x
WHERE LOWER(x."Name") = '5'
```

Result: 1 Row

Comment: not familiar with postgre, but could'nt the query be simplified by a good collation choice ? And btw, what is the default collation for your query ? Isn' it sommething like latin_CI ? that is tolower is useless too

Comment: Any chance you could submit a minimal example of Trim not working, on specific data? It's hard to tell from your issue what is going on.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Done.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried reproducing your issue but could not. The following code sample seems to work fine, please double-check your query and setup, and if you still think something is wrong, please submit a sample similar to the one below which demonstrates the issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new BlogContext())
        {
            ctx.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();

            ctx.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Name = "5" });
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var ctx = new BlogContext())
        {
            var blog = ctx.Blogs.Single(b => b.Name.Trim().ToLower() == "5");
            Console.WriteLine(blog.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=test;Username=npgsql_tests;Password=npgsql_tests");
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

SQL generated:

```
SELECT b."Id", b."Name"
    FROM "Blogs" AS b
    WHERE LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(b."Name", '^\s*(.*?)\s*$', '\1')) = '5'
    LIMIT 2
```